# Where did the badge system come from?

Tags: discussion, badges, stack-exchange-history

One of the interesting things about Stack Exchange is the **badge system**. I think it makes things more fun and competitive, while encouraging users to **work and help** the **community**.

I was wondering **where this idea came from**, and if our badge system was inspired by some other group/technology. [I know](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81900/origins-of-the-badge-system) that this is an old reward system within the military, but I wonder who first brought it to a virtual community.

FourSquare, Empire Avenue and other social networks have implemented their own badge systems that work very similarly to ours, and I can't help thinking that they were influenced by Stack Exchange.

**Did we copy this system from somebody else?**

Comment: Last time I checked, they were inspired by [Xbox Achievements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xbox_Live).

Comment: Ok, but was it a conscious decision like "Let's do something like Xbox Achievements!" ?

Comment: The university of wisconsin campus police. ("Where are your badge(rs)?")

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A recent [Jeff blog on Gamification](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2011/10/the-gamification.html) suggests that badges may well be inspired by the Xbox 360 achievements...

> When Joel Spolsky and I set out to design the Stack Exchange Q&A
>   engine in 2008 -- then known as Stack Overflow -- we borrowed
>   liberally and unapologetically from any online system that we felt
>   worked. Some of our notable influences included:
>
> - Reddit and Digg voting
> - Xbox 360 achievements
> - Wikipedia editing
> - eBay karma
> - Blogs and blog comments
> - Classic web bulletin boards

Answer (score 5):

As NullUserException noted in the comment and davidsleeps noted in the other answer, this was [inspired by the XBox](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/07/stack-overflow-badge-feedbac/):

> As I mentioned in Podcast #13 (and probably earlier), Stack Overflow will feature a system of badges. Hopefully the non-stinking type. These badges are based on my admiration — and addiction to — the Xbox 360 Achievements system.

Comment: +1 I guess I need to start reading the blog as well. Thanks!